# Evolution does not encrypt my emails

Tags: gpg, evolution

I am using Elementary OS 0.4.1, Evolution for my gmail account. Additional, I use GPG to encrypt my emails I send to my friends.
I did a reinstall of eOS on my laptop. Please note, I kept my home folder on separate partition than root.
After reinstall, evolution is not encrypting my email, before sending email it is showing following error:

`Could not create message.
Because "gpg: using subkey BB84D566 instead of primary key CEF41E5C
gpg: using PGP trust model
gpg: This key belongs to us
gpg: CC461E31: There is no assurance this key belongs to the named user
gpg: [stdin]: encryption failed: Unusable public key
", you may need to select different mail options.`

I have already given OpenKey Id for the account I am using.
Please help me out, thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that it wasn't the fault of Evolution. I had to trust my friend's GPG keys (`CC461E31`) for encryption to work. This would be a solution. Another will be, and I quote from mailing list,

`Configure evolution not to check that and instead assume that if you
have a OpenPGP key in your keyring for a given email, it should encrypt
the messages for that recipient using that key:
Edit → Preferences → (Choose your account) → Edit → Security → Check
Always trust keys in my keyring when encrypting`